# delete a particular row from session array

Tags: php

I am a beginner in php. 
I want to know how a particular row in a php session array can be deleted(not from the database, but from the page only). 
I have a table namely, issues having columns issue_id & issue_descrp.
The page is displayed with a table in which each row contains issue and its corresponding id. Each row contain a delete button too. What I want is to delete the corresponding row from the page when I click the button.
This is my php code:

```
    <?php

    foreach($_SESSION['meeting_issues'] as $meeting_issues)
        {
            $query="select issue_id,issue from issues where issue_id='$meeting_issues'";
            $result=$_SESSION['connection']->query($query) or die (mysql_error());
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
            {?>
                <?php $issue_id=$row['issue_id']; ?>
                <tr><td><?php echo $row['issue_id']; ?></td><td><?php echo $row['issue']; ?></td><td><input type="button" name="<?php echo $row['issue_id']; ?>" id="button" value="Remove"/></td>
                </tr>
                <?php
            }       
        }
        ?>
```

Hope my question is clear. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

use unset to delete array elements such as those in `$_SESSION`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php

do not delete the whole session this way, use this instead

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-unset.php

Comment: but i cant delete it by specifying unset.
can u please suggest me how to do it....?
Thanks..

Comment: i know am asking dump questions..but please help me..
how can i remove that particular row in the button click?

Comment: so you have to remember that the server and the clients browser are two completely different realms. if you are looking to just delete it from a page, then you should look into js, like Rune suggested. if you want to delete it out of your database, then you need to run a mysql DELETE query, using issue_id.

Answer (score 1):

To remove a row on the page itself, you will need `Javascript` or `jQuery`. jQuery is advised because of all the possibilities it gives and it is easier to use than normal Javascript.

jQuery:

```
$("#button").parents("tr:closest").remove();
```

Javascript:

```
document.getElementById('button').parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(document.getElementById('button').parentNode.parentNode);
```

As you can see, jQuery is alot faster and more easy to type.

You are using an ID for the buttons, but the ID is always the same. I recommend using classes for this, because an ID should be unique on a page.

[jQuery website](http://jquery.com/)